# Android Json unicode parsin

Tags: android, json, unicode

my sql server collation is utf8 unicode
my php works fine 
my android project is working fine with normal characters but in case of arabic char it display error "Error parsing json" line 233 in the activity listed below 
I've tried my sql and php on other project its works but here I dont know whats the error json must be utf8 by defult

public class DealsListActivity extends Activity {

```
private String id;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


private static String url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.get_all_deals_by_id.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_DEALS = "deals";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_DEALNAME = "dealName";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_RESTID = "restID";
private static final String TAG_RESTNAME = "restName";
private static final String TAG_RESTTYPE = "restType";
private static final String TAG_LAT = "restLat";
private static final String TAG_LNG = "restLng";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

private JSONObject json;

JSONArray restaurantDealsData = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurantDealsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView myList;

private String[] dealID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deals_list);

    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id. restDealListView);

    new LoadDeals().execute();
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all deals by making
 * HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadDeals extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DealsListActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Restaurant Deals. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Log.v("id", id);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
        // check log cat for JSON string from URL
        Log.v("restaurantDealsJSON: ", json.toString());

        // return json as string to using in the user interface
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String jsonStr) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into listview
                 * */
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // print error message to log
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                    error("There are no Deals");

                }

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCES TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // restaurant found


                        // Getting Array of restaurant

                        restaurantDealsData = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DEALS);
                        displayDeals(restaurantDealsData.toString());
                    } else {

                        error("There is no Deals available!");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    error("There has been an error please try again!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void error(String error) {
    // Log.v("ERROR", "2");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            DealsListActivity.this);
    // Log.v("ERROR", "3");
    builder.setTitle("Error");
    builder.setMessage(error);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Log.v("TEST", "1");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void displayDeals(String result) {
    JSONArray restaurantDealsData = null;

    try {
        restaurantDealsList.clear();

        restaurantDealsData = new JSONArray(result);

        dealID = new String[restaurantDealsData.length()];
        // looping through all technical data
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurantDealsData.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject td = restaurantDealsData.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = td.getString(TAG_ID);
            dealID[i] = id;

            String name = td.getString(TAG_DEALNAME);
            String price = td.getString(TAG_PRICE);
            String description = td.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            String restaurantID = td.getString(TAG_RESTID);
            String restaurantName = td.getString(TAG_RESTNAME);
            String restaurantType = td.getString(TAG_RESTTYPE);
            String lat = td.getString(TAG_LAT);
            String lng = td.getString(TAG_LNG);

            Log.v("lat", lat);
            Log.v("lng", lng);

            // Creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_DEALNAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
            map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            map.put(TAG_RESTID, restaurantID);
            map.put(TAG_RESTNAME, restaurantName);
            map.put(TAG_RESTTYPE, restaurantType);
            map.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
            map.put(TAG_LNG, lng);


            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
            restaurantDealsList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        error("Error parsing json");
    }

    // add to list view
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            restaurantDealsList, R.layout.deals_list_item, new String[] {
                    TAG_DEALNAME, TAG_RESTNAME, TAG_RESTTYPE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.dealName, R.id.restaurantName, R.id.type });
    // updating listview
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //handling user click list item
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //start the next activity - Restaurant Details
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DealDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("ID", dealID[arg2]);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }

    });
}
```

}

public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your `JSONParser` to the question?

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN yes I just added it check it now

Comment: The parser has no problems, What's the line 233 in the activity?

Comment: displayingdeals part of the activity above

Comment: Hi! Why don't you set JSONArray parameter (instead of String) for displayDeals?

Comment: I have to change many activities :( @BNK

Comment: Have you debugged into displayDeals yet? Inside it, you will find out why exception and what line of code causes that.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the input stream using the charset UTF-8 like this:

replace

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

by

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8));
```

I use this to decode json with japanese inside.

Comment: still the same problem